# Как правильно использовать слово "добавлять"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Как правильно сказать: *я добавлю на сковородку лук, затем добавлю чеснок, потом добавлю соль* или надо говорить *я положу на сковородку лук, затем положу чеснок, потом положу соль?* Правильно ли здесь употребление слова "добавлю"?

Answer (score 1):

Добавить можно что-то к чему-то. На пустую сковородку лук добавить не к чему, поэтому если вы его кладёте первым, тогда лучше сказать так:

> Я положу на сковородку лук, затем добавлю чеснок, потом посолю (добавлю соль).

Второй вариант тоже не выглядит неправильным, сказать так можно. Если же вы первый из перечисленных ингредиентов, лук, кладёте не первым, а действительно добавляете к чему-то уже жарящемуся или тушащемуся на сковородке, то и ваш первый вариант подойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря Т. Ф. Ефремовой:
**добавлять**, несов. перех. (*добавить*, сов. перех.)
**1.** а) ***Прибавлять*** к уже имеющемуся что-л. недостающее, дополнять до
необходимого, нужного количества, объема и т.п.
б) ***Присоединять*** дополнительно что-л. к чему-л.
в) ***Увеличивать*** количество чего-л.

Если на сковороде ***хоть что-нибудь*** уже имеется, то только тогда можно использовать глаголы *добавить/добавлять*.

Разогреть в небольшой сковороде сливочное масло, добавить нарубленный лук и мускатный орех и тушить 2 минуты (из рецепта).